# Get specific product descriptions from all stores

Tags: product, attributes, stores

I need to get all product descriptions(and maybe some other attributes).
For example, for product with id 2:

- Store id 1: "First store description"
- Store id 2: "Second store description"
- Store id 3: "Third store description"

Is there some different way than getting all store id's and then in a loop for each one store id load product with id 2 and getting it's own description?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you don't want to loop through all the store ids and you just want to loop through the ones that the product Id 2 has the stores:

```
$item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
$storeIds = $item->getStoreIds();
```

then you loop through the stores of product id 2  and you get descriptions:

```
    foreach($storeIds as $storeId)
   Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

To load a product without looping like the below example, you can set the store id, like so:

```
$storeId = 2; // or whatever store you want

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->load($_product->getId());
```

Then grab the info as usual ..

```
$product->getName();
```

etc ..

.. the loop method is:

```
foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {

    foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {

        $stores = $group->getStores();

        foreach ($stores as $store) {

            // store id
            $storeId = $store->getId();

            // do your other stuff here ...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, but it is not the way i'm looking for :)

Comment: I've edited my answer =)

Comment: Yep, but then I have to load product for each element from store id's array(1,2,3, 4..). That is the same as below, with difference that we know desire store ids. I'm interesting for some simply and elegance solution or confirmation that this no way out than loading product for each store id.

Comment: Ah ok, so you want something like this to work: `$product->setStoreId($storeId)->getName();` to grab the info without loading the product for the store view first? I don't think this works, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that could be great, but it returns only default name, unfortunately..

Comment: This code only links product to the specific store instead of getting value from it.

Comment: Well, as far as I can see you need to specify the storeid when you load the product or filter by it when you load a collection of products - i don't know of a way to directly grab the product info for a storeview without having to load the specific product first